# Refactoring code in OOP PHP and using PDO for mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I am new to OOP in PHP. I am having a problem while I am trying to refactor my code in OOP and PDO. The problem occurred when I tried refactor my code. So I have a category class to manage category CRUD operations. To read all the previously created categories I have a method

```
    public function readAll(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " ORDER  BY modified ASC";
       $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
         if($stmt->execute()){
            return $stmt;
          } 
  }
```

And within the same class in the construct function I am getting my db connection like so

```
public function __construct(PDO $db){
    $this->connection = $db;
}
```

and I am calling the read all method in my page like this -

```
 $allCategories= $category->readAll();
```

and it works just fine but  when I tried to refactor my code to use a new function like this-

```
    private function doQuery($query){
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
         if($stmt->execute()){
            return $stmt;
          }    
    }
    public function readAll(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " ORDER  BY modified ASC";
      $this->doQuery($query);
  }
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\image-upload\category.php on line 222
```

So I just want to save myself from having to write prepare and execute statements every time I make a different query. I am trying to make my code DRY. I may be missing something. A slight hint in the right direction is highly appreciated. Please help me.

" THANKS IN ADVANCE "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your second readAll() method returns nothing. It should read

```
return $this->doQuery($query);
```

or, rather, based on the method's name

```
return $this->doQuery($query)->fetchAll();
```

to get an array with all the rows selected.

Aside from this trifle issue, there is a mistake in the doQuery() method, making it utterly useless. It have to be

```
private function doQuery($query, $data = array()){
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    return $stmt;
}
```

allowing you to use **placeholders** to represent actual data variables in the query

Comment: Thank You very much Sir. It solved my problem. One more thing I wanted to ask you is that, Is it OK to pass an Array in the execute method in PDO or should I use bindParam and bindValue because passing an array seems more convenient to me.

Comment: If this has solved your question you should mark this is the best answer

Comment: Hello JammyDodger231. I have created the account in stackoverflow today and I am not familiar how to do what you said. Can you please tell me how can I mark this as the best answer because I can't see any options to do that. Excuse my ignorance

Comment: @RoyCoder http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work